# How can I make a 320 pixel wide mobile site zoom to full width when rotated to landscape?

Tags: mobile, viewport

I've been trying numerous viewport combinations, but can't seem to find the right one.

I have a mobile site that is built to be 320 pixels wide. I'd like these 320 pixels to stretch the full width of the screen in both portrait and landscape mode, regardless of which orientation the screen starts out with, or whether the viewer rotates the device.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is the point of using fixed pixel values when you want the site to stretch? 
Just use

```
width: 100%
```